# Can't access on local internal ip address on Windows

Tags: ip, ip-address, jhipster, internal

I install JHipster, i can access with http://localhost:8083, but with the internal address ip http://192.168.0.55:8083, i can't.

ipconfig:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection :
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.0.55
   Sub mask. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.254
```

Display address when start jhipster:

---

```
    Application 'store' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:          http://localhost:8083
    External:       http://192.168.0.55:8083
        Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
-----------------------------------------------------
```

On my other laptop i can access without problem, but with this company's laptop, i have problem, i think first, it's because of some proxy...but i don't really know.

Thanks you

Comment: Is it accessible at http://192.168.0.37:8083, the address reported as external by JHipster?

Comment: Sorry Jon, writing error, the external ip is http://192.168.0.55:8083, on this laptop i can't access. I don't know why...